# What bug has similar legs to a prawn?

Tags: species-identification, zoology, arthropod

This is a bug that I observe in Melbourne.

This bug is living in wet places and jumping a few centimeters while its length is 8.5mm.

It does not have insect legs. It's legs are more similar to prawn.

Sorry my camera cannot capture a better picture as the bug is too small.

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Springtail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is "Lawn Shrimp", an Australian indigenous creature. It is harmless.

Comment: Hello ar, welcome to Biology. This answer is very brief and adds little beyond what another answer has already stated except an additional nickname of the species and a great (but redundant) picture. Please refer to our [help] for guidance on how to answer questions. Enjoy the site.

Comment: @ARogueAnt., I wonder why you call this answer redundant when the previous answer does not specify the type of the creature. It only refers to the family of it. I see no "lawn shrimp" in the answer above.

Comment: Whilst the picture you've supplied appears to belong to the same family as the other answer, lawn shrimp usually refers to Arcitalitrus sylvaticus which is quite a bit smaller than the size specified in the question (and a different colour, but that may not matter). --Unless I've misread or misunderstood the descriptions.

Comment: @ARogueAnt., I have no better photo. I removed it.

Answer (score 2):

This is a ["sand hopper" (Talitridae)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talitridae), also known as "land hoppers" or "sand fleas". The Talitridae are a cosmopolitan family of arthropods, known for their hopping behaviour when disturbed.

Which of the genera it is from would be impossible to determine without detailed close-up pictures and a bit of expert knowledge which is well outside my expertise.